# Do the Guardian of Nature spell's benefits carry over to a druid in Wild Shape?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, druid, wild-shape

If my level 7 druid casts [*guardian of nature*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/guardian-of-nature) (choosing the Primal Beast form) on himself and then proceeds to use [Wild Shape](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/druid#WildShape), do the effects of the spell carry over to the Wild Shape?

Comment: Hi otat, and welcome to the site. This question is great, but I think it can be answered the same way as an existing question. Let us know in the comments if you disagree. Also, check out the [tour](/tour) to get a badge.

Answer (score 10):

Yep, *Guardian of Nature* will carry over and affect you while you're Wild Shaped. With some exceptions.

> Transforming doesn't break your concentration on a spell you've already cast [...]

So, to start with, the spell won't end just because you use Wild Shape. Furthermore:

> You retain the benefit of any features from your class, race, or other source and can use them if the new form is physically capable of doing so. However, you can't use any of your special senses, such as darkvision, unless your new from also has that sense.

So the features you gain from the spell (which comes under "other sources") will work if the new form is capable of using them.

> - Your walking speed increases by 10 feet.

Anything that can walk should be capable of using this feature. I'd rule that a form which doesn't have a walking speed, such as a quipper or seahorse, isn't capable of using this.

> - You gain darkvision with a range of 120 feet.

As the quote says, you can't use darkvision unless your Wild Shape form already has it. If it does, it should get the 120 foot range. Probably. [It's not completely clear.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/90450/15469)

> - You make Strength-based attack rolls with advantage.

Ok, this one's a bit weird, because monsters don't specify whether their attacks are Strength-based. You'll have to work with your DM on a case-by-case basis to find out whether this applies. (It's pretty easy to tell when a creature's attacks are Strength-based, though.)

> - Your melee weapon attacks deal an extra 1d6 force damage on a hit.

Yep. Everything you can Wild Shape into has some sort of melee weapon attack, so you'll always be able to use this.

Comment: With normal weapons, the tacit assumption is that weapons use Strength unless noted otherwise. The same understanding would make sense for natural weapons as well.

Comment: @Bagahnoodles no - you need to look at the attack bonus for the attack, take away the proficiency bonus the CR gives and then work out if what is left matches the STR or DEX bonus

Comment: Guardian of nature is a spell, not a feature so it gives your Wildshape dark vision so long as your Wildshape is not blind.

Comment: You can wild shape into an ape and gain a missile weapon attack.  So while you *can* always use the extra force damage, that doesn't mean you *will* always be using it.

Answer (score -2):

so my DM and I were looking at the wording. We would say that this spell is one that would not work with Wild Shape. While I love the idea of buffing your Wild Shapes, when you use Wild Shape, youTransform into the animal form. The spell is a transmutation spell that specifically says it transforms you. These would be two conflicting transformations. 
So the way the spell and Wild Shape are written, my DM and I think it would not work together.